# How to read the JSON response

Tags: js-controller

I am getting the below JSON response inside a variable('responsebody') from client-side

```
{
  "predictions": [
    {
      "description": "812 West 11th Street, Coffeyville, KS, USA",
      "structured_formatting": {
        "main_text": "812 West 11th Street",
        "secondary_text": "Coffeyville, KS, USA"
      },
      "types": [
        "street_address",
        "geocode"
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "810 Keith Boulevard, Coffeyville, KS, USA",
      "structured_formatting": {
        "main_text": "810 Keith Boulevard",
        "secondary_text": "Coffeyville, KS, USA"
      },
      "types": [
        "street_address",
        "geocode"
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "806 North Buckeye Street, Coffeyville, KS, USA",
      "structured_formatting": {
        "main_text": "806 North Buckeye Street",
        "secondary_text": "Coffeyville, KS, USA"
      },
      "types": [
        "street_address",
        "geocode"
      ]
    }
],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

I am trying to get the values for the description key like below:

```
for(var a in responsebody.predictions){
console.log(a.description);
}
```

but the output is "Undefined" can anyone help me how to get all the  description field values.

Answer (score 1):

You probably first want to parse that string into a JS object

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(responsebody);
```

Then this should work

```
for(var a in myObject.predictions){
    console.log(a.description);
}
```

Comment: Hi Sebastian, i tried but it says Undefined

Comment: It's not possible for me to help you further without significantly expanded context. Feel free to edit your original post with more code and we'll review